# import multiple images ans store them in list using mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am using Mathematica to enhance and thin images. I used it for single image, now i want to use it for multiple images. so I have to import 6 images, do the thining  and store them in a list for example. Can any one show me how to do that??
The images will be used for biometrics identification system.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a list as a result you might think of using either Table or Map. Either of those can do n things, one after another, and put the result into your final list.

Since you didn't show the steps you used for processing a single list it is a little difficult to tell you exactly how to wrap Table or Map around this.

If you have a list of image file names then you could use Map to process those names one at a time. The processing could either be a compound function to Import the image and then enhance and thin and the output of that function would be a single processed image. Map would then do the repetition over all the names.

Table might work in a similar way, but you use each iteration to get the file name, do the processing and store the result in your desired list.